# Found Eigenvector is close to the solution but not correct, what step am I missing?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

While practicing finding eigenvectors I have this matrix A:
\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 0\\
0 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
The eigenvalues I found are $\lambda = 9,4$

(A) In finding the corresponding eigenvector to $\lambda=9$, I did:

$A-I\lambda$
\begin{bmatrix}
9-9 & 0\\
0 & 4-9
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & -5
\end{bmatrix}

$-\frac{1}{5}R2 \rightarrow R2$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Then I swapped R1 and R2
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

(B) and got the eigenvector :
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}

But when I used those online calculators to check they gave me:
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}

Was I supposed to swap the columns in step (A) similar to row echelon form? I did not think to do that during my calculations since the second row is all zeros, but I am thinking that may be wrong. If someone can confirm if that is the missing step, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: the square matrix you show in part A   is completely wrong.

Comment: @WillJagy I re-did the problem and added in the steps to show what I did, though I still got the same matrix and so I don't see what you mean. Are you able to elaborate more now?

Comment: Your final matrix translates to the system of linear equations $x_2=0$. Yet you give as a solution a vector of the form $(x_1,x_2)^T=(0,1)^T$, that is, one that does *not* satisfy the system. Why?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay I see what you mean. I don't see how it doesn't satisy the system because when I checked it by doing Ax (where x is my incorrect eigenvector), I got, following your notation, $(0,4)^T$ which is a scalar of x. So it is clear I am missing some sort of knowledge here. Also, with the given original matrix, you would end up with either $x_1=0$ or $x_2 = 0$ for each eigenvalue, no? How can I correctly determine which corresponds to the correct eigenvalue? If I am not being clear, let know and I shall rephrase.

Comment: Actually, is that itself the issue? That when multiplying the reduced row echelon matrix by $(x_1,x_2)^T$ (while set equal to $(0,0)^T$) and like above I get $x_2=0$ that I am supposed to let it be equal to some parameter, s, and then let the other value $x_1=0$ (and vice versa)?

Comment: You are lost. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and you calculate $A-\lambda I$, what you are then looking for is vectors $x$ such that $(A-\lambda I)x=\mathbf{0}$, not vectors that are mapped to nonzero scalar multiples of themselves.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, that is correct. Conceptually, I understand. It is computationally that is it does not match up and I am not sure where specifically. Is this one of those things where I look (or test and then adjust accordingly) and see if I have to "flip" the eigenvector? I think I may just be saying incorrect things.

Comment: No, you do not understand, conceptually or otherwise, and instead are wasting time writing nonsense. How about you take the matrix A, or the matrixB, and actually try to solve, **explicitly**, the equation $M\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$? Don't "conceptualize". Just **solve**.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I did solve it directly in that form, reached the same conclusion multiple times, and still was unable to pinpoint what I am doing specifically. That was the purpose of this post, to see if someone can clarify. I am a person who is trying to learn something new and unfamiliar and your last comment did not provide any guidance. Since you seem to have lost patience, you are able to stop engaging in what is now a lengthy comment section.

Comment: Then you need to review how to solve equations properly. For matrix A and matrix B, the solutions have the form $(a,0)^T$ with $a$ arbitrary, yet you insist that you are solving them and getting the vector $(0,1)^T$? Let me put it plainly: solving with either matrix should be trivial, yet you get the wrong answer multiple times? You don't know how to solve a system that says $0=0$ and $x_2=0$? Then you don't know how to solve equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the eigenvalue $\lambda = 9$. You want to find a corresponding eigenvector, that is, a vector $x$ such that $Ax = 9x$, or equivalently, $(A-9I)x = 0$. Writing this as a matrix equation,
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & -5 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
So we want to find the $x_1, x_2$ that would make this true. To do this with row reduction, you have to remember what the values in the matrix represent, coefficients for $x_1$ and $x_2$. Swapping rows, multiplying by scalars, and adding rows do not change the underlying system. So we do those steps to make the matrix as simple as posssible before solving. Swapping columns is **not** allowed - this can completely change the system!

Your row reduction to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is correct. Putting that back in our matrix equation: $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
Multiplying out to get the "traditional" system of equations, just so it is clearer what things mean.

$$\begin{align*} 0 x_1 + 1 x_ 2 & = 0 \\ 0 x_1 + 0 x_2&= 0\end{align*}$$
The second equation just says $0+0 = 0$, so that does not give any information. The first tells us $x_2 = 0$. In conclusion, $x_1$ is free (can be anything) and $x_2 = 0$. As a vector, this looks like $ \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ for $x_1$ being any number. You may recall that any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue. So we can simply state the eigenvector for $\lambda = 9$ is $ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, knowing that this means any scalar multiple of that vector works, which is exactly what solving the equation told us. And to double check $$ \begin{bmatrix} 9 & 0\\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}9 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 9 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
This is exactly what we expect from an eigenvector for $\lambda = 9$, that $Ax = 9x$.

I hope this clarifies things and wasn't too long winded. Once you're very familiar with using row reduction to solve systems of equations, you might be able to do this without writing as many steps out. But for now, I would write out the "traditional" system of equations to make sure it is clear what is happening.

Comment: Your explanation is thorough and clear. I figured out my issue was that I was misinterpretting the results and how to represent them. I got $x_2=0$ and because that was the variable left, what I was doing was taking it's coefficient, 1, and I was thinking of $x_1$ as $0x_1$ and this is how I got my incorrrect eigenvector. Of course now it is clear what is going on, that I just take their respective values, i.e. like you said: $x_2=0$ and let $x_1=s$ thus giving the correct eigenvector).